# UIWebview White Page

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

Why is this happening? I can not understand. What am I doing wrong? When I run the simulator I'm having this problem.

Code :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var websayfasi: UIWebView!
    var urlpath = "http://google.com.tr "

    func loadAdressURL(){

        let requestURL = NSURL (string:urlpath)

        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
        websayfasi.loadRequest(request)
        self.view.addSubview(websayfasi)    
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5z4pU.png)

Comment: I can't C either IBOutlet or frame defined to the webView ....

Comment: Ensure that the webView has defines frame ... By IBOuylet R programmatically...

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the App Transport Security Settings of your application. Apple recently added extra security measures for arbitrary http loads. Try the following method:

Step 1: Go to your info.plist file

Step 2: Add a new key: "App Transport Security Settings"

Step 3: Add a boolean subkey, "Allow Arbitrary Loads", set it to YES

Step 4: Add a dictionary subkey, "Exception Domains"

Step 5: Add a string subkey to "Exception Domains" with the url causing you the error (http://www.google.com.tr in this case)

At the end, it should look like this (with your url of course)

[image]

Comment: Yes this s true ... But if that could be the case then the op would be notified warning by console ...

Comment: Well, he never clarified if he did get a console message here, so I'm considering it a possibly. I have run into this same issue if I do not add the domain to ATSS

Comment: Yes it might be ... Keep the answer, might helpful others as well If this s the case ..

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();
        self.loadAdressURL()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var websayfasi: UIWebView!
    var urlpath = "http://google.com.tr "


    func loadAdressURL()
    {
        let url : String = urlpath!;
        let t = NSURL(string: url);
        webSayfasi.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: t!));

    }
```

Can you try like this ?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your function; however, you forgot to call it

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    loadAdressURL();
}
```

Also you don't need `self.view.addSubview(websayfasi)` if you are using AutoLayout.